# Setting up cygwin

Tags: path, include, cygwin, visual-studio-code

I'm setting up cygwin in windows 10. I've installed required devel and tried to run simple hello world code in VSCode. I've set my VSCode includePath to:

C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\6.4.0\include\c++

However, I got this error of missing stdio.h file in my include folder. Only that afaik, since stdlib works fine.
Any idea or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the header of cygwin gcc compiler with a VS compiler that is not a cygwin program.

In general on cygwin you should use a cygwin compiler; both gcc and clang are available.